# assigning new ip address

Tags: ip

my girlfriend has the ip address to my computer and is getting onto my computer and stealing stuff. i use linux and was wondering if i could assign a new ip address other than thru my internet provider, which i will do if there is no other way.

i looked up online and found the following article: http://www.wikihow.com/Assign-an-IP-Address-on-a-Linux-Computer

Is it possible to assign a new REAL IP ADDRESS, not just masking my real ip address which wouldn't be of any use.

cheers!

Comment: It is no problem to change the ip-address but in this case I suspect you mean the external ip on the internet. You could change that but your provider wil probably not accept your self-chosen ip. Would become a bit messy out there if everyone just starts jumping ip :)

Comment: You have a static IP through your ISP? Easiest solution would be to put a router or firewall between your modem and computer and only open the necessary incoming ports you need.

Comment: I've often found that leaving the router off for a few days leads to a new external IP. How is your girlfriend getting in anyway? Surely you should be looking to plug that hole rather than just change IP (it's like you planning to move house because she knows your address, and is stealing from you, instead of just getting a bigger bolt on your door, which would stop her and everyone else stealing from you...)

Comment: thanks. this is the deal. i'm using the library and someone is directly connecting to my computer b/c they know the ip of the library; trust me, that is how they are connecting to my computer. I could tell you why but i'll forego that for now.

Comment: thanks. this is the deal. i'm using my laptop/ library and someone is directly connecting to my computer b/c they know the lib's ip; trust me, that is how they are connecting to my computer. There are 2 options: secure my computer, though they are experts at getting through the most secure comp systems and quickly! i would rather change the ip address for my comp (i'm guessing internal). this way if they connect to the lib sys they wouldn't get on my comp. THen again, changing the internal wouldn't affect the lib ip i'm guessing. i've had ubuntu firewall on but doesn't seem to prevent x.thx

Comment: What you are implying would mean at the very least they would have to be in the library **at the same time as you are**. The layers that anyone on the outside that someone would have to breach make that highly improbable. And the odds of you getting **consistently** the same DHCP-assigned IP address on a publicly-shared network are low as well. If you have conclusive log evidence to show the "break-ins", please add them to your question. Otherwise, I would be inclined to conclude paranoia on your part and vote to have this question removed.

Comment: like i said, they have the library's ip and they connect to the public computer system / network using that ip. whenever they connect they let me know by writing something on my computer. how does this work: DHCP-assigned IP address on a publicly-shared network? it seems as though whether or not i use my laptop or public computer, the  ip address is the same; not familiar with  DHCP-assigned IP address on a publicly-shared network.

Comment: s this all started when i accidentally downloaded a RAT virus while using the public computer. they got onto my pub computer deleted something from my flash drive that i had just put on the flash drive moments before. i know they deleted it b/c i used the recovery software to get it back. so they did get on the public computer thru the RAT virus, no doubt about that; hence lack of paranoia. if it would be just as difficult for them to get through the public computer system using the RAT virus, then it would seem simple for them to connect to the public computers using the library's ip address.

Comment: 2 posts b/f this one (by user229656) are together

Comment: If you believe that a RAT program has been installed on your machine, your best course of action would be seeking out an anti-virus/malware removal tool. Google is your friend. Use another computer to download it, install it on your computer and run it without being connected to any networks.

Comment: thanks. question: if u have the ip address that i connect to for the internet, even if you live out of state, couldn't you connect to my computer from that alone?
- if you have the mac address of my computer, couldn't a good hacker connect to my computer with that alone? when they got onto the library computer window os, the only thing they could have gotten was the library ip address; i never connected to the library network that day with my laptop. the next day they connected to my laptop while i was connected to the library's network. thanks!

Comment: i have an excellent RAT removal tool - dban.

Comment: 2 messages above together..........

Answer (score 0):

Turn router off overnight, hope lease expires, get new IP (it may take longer than this).

Alternatively change MAC address of router, either via cloning/spoofing (if router supports this..see the manufacturer webpage), or just request a new router from ISP (or buy new router).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. However, since you need to change the IP address to static, the only way is to set-up a manual/static IP editing the /etc/network/interfaces file. for that you need to edit the interfaces file with;

```
sudo nano /etc/network/intarfaces
```

You'll ideally see something like;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace it with;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
```

Moving further, if you have or require domain to be resolved along with DNS servers, you may add few more lines to the file, similar to;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
```

Please note, there are two sets of x.x.x.x within the DNS name servers (Primary and Secondary) with a space. You may use one pair or both depending on your requirement.

To save the file select ctrl+o, -> enter and exit with ctrl+x.

And then just to be sure, simple restart the interface with;

```
 sudo ifdown eth0           # wait for sometime
    sudo ifup eth0             # and then issue this to restart
```

Also, as a final step, simply type below to confirm the interface change;

```
ifconfig -a
```

**Alternative way;**

Refer to your server or the device which responds to DHCP requests and add a reservation, in case if you do not like to play with the server, files.. etc.

In order to get the MAC address for reservation, simply check the interface information with a;

```
ifconfig eth0                 # or type ifconfig -a
```

which should ideally display something similar to below;

```
ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:c5ff:fe4a:165a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:466475604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:403172654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2574778386 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:1618367329 (1.6 GB)
          Interrupt:16
```

Where you see the `HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a` and assign it to the DHCP reservation.

Hope this helps!